# how to invoke system() for date command in C

Tags: c, shell

I have been trying to invoke the library function **system()** to call `date` in a C program

It's not displaying any output.

```
int main()    
{    
 char cmd[20];
 strcpy(cmd, "date");
 system(cmd);
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: implement `date`  != `system(date)`

Comment: and BTW, did you include `stdlib.h`?

Comment: also, try providing full path to `date` binary, for example, `/bin/date` or equivalent.

Comment: It's displaying output for me..

Comment: Upvote for the correct activation of the built-in homework solving automation mechanism of SO. ;)

Comment: Please explain us what you want to do exactly : such as desired input (if any) and desired output.

Comment: **Always** check the return code from library calls.

Comment: http://ideone.com/u3PXtV works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use gettimeofday() to get everything Date Time or whatever . For Example :

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;

  time_t curtime;



  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
  curtime=tv.tv_sec;

  strftime(buffer,30,"%m-%d-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
  printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);

  return 0;



}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple function `ctime()`.It will print `which day of week` `month` `day of month` `time` and then `year` .

```
     #include <time.h>
     #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
       {
          time_t mytime;
          mytime = time(NULL);
          printf(ctime(&mytime));

          return 0;
        }
```

The function returns a C string containing the date and time information.It will convert the `time_t` object pointed by the timer to a C string.